# System.AccessViolationException in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, filestream

```
// diskbin.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  //code

  if(stat("key.pc.db", &filek) ==0 )
      sizek=filek.st_size;
  if(stat("seek.pc.db", &files) ==0 )
      sizes=files.st_size;

  sizek=sizek/sizeof(int);
  sizes=sizes/sizeof(int);
  int i,min,max,mid;
  int *s=new int[sizes];
  int *hit=new int[sizes];

  //code
}
```

When I run this program in Visual Studio 2008, I am not getting any error but when I run the cmd opens and then closes followed by a pop up window which says:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in diskbin.exe
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." What could be the issue? Have I not allocated s and hit properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Either you're not getting any error, or you're getting an error. Pick one.

Comment: Do some debugging. What line does the program crash at?

Comment: @Martino I meant its not showing any on the error window. It shows 0 errors and 0 warnings.

Comment: So you're saying it's compiling, but crashing... where does it crash?

Comment: at the `int *s=new int[sizes];` statement.

Comment: I know, check out my answer. I ran the code and it also crashed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am getting the same error in a different program. Is this statement the problem -                                           `int max_index=100;               
int max_avail=100;
vector<index_S> vec_index(max_index);     
vector<avail_S> vec_avail(max_avail);`?                               Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because you're using uninitialized variables:

```
  int       sizes, sizek;
  struct stat files, filek;
  ofstream ofs;

  if(stat("key.pc.db", &filek) ==0 )
      sizek=filek.st_size;
  if(stat("seek.pc.db", &files) ==0 )
      sizes=files.st_size;

  sizek=sizek/sizeof(int);
  sizes=sizes/sizeof(int);
```

if stat() fails, you use an uninitialized sizek.
Depending on the uninitialized memory, your next statement will crash:

```
int *s=new int[sizes];
```

because `sizes` can be negative or a very large number and the new will fail.

Check the error returned by stat(), although it's possible the file `key.pc.db` is not found, causing the function to fail.

Comment: hmm I asked a similar question yesterday and I was suggested to use new. I don't have a constant value to assign it to. What else can I do?

Comment: don't use a constant value. The cause is stat() fails, you should investigate that, not change your code just so it works. Check whether the files are there.

Comment: Also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff(VS.71).aspx and look for reasons for the failure.

Comment: @Richa - Do _not_ use uninitialized variables, as this answer says. If your fixed version which does not use uninitialized variables still crashes, come back and tell us where it does.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Got it, I had stored the file in a wrong location.